# google sheets sumif not working with checkBoxes

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Hello so I have a google sheet where I am running some scripts depending on some values on sheet, one of them should be a sum of rows where a checkbox is checked, however, when I try to do the sumif that fulfills this condition, it does not work, here is what I tried so far:
[image]

also I tried to do the same while switch the value and checkbox column but I still have the same problem so there must be something I am missing out, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B18:B25*A18:A25)
```

[image]

this works for me too `=sumif(B18:B25,true,A18:A25)`

Comment: thank you, the sumProduct() worked for me, however, the "=sumif(B18:B25,true,A18:A25)" did not.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do:

```
=SUM(IFNA(FILTER(FILTER(A18:A25; B18:B25=TRUE)))
```